# Unable to use .format with an API call, Vmware Aria Automation Config

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am working with VMWare Aria Automation Config [API](https://developer.vmware.com/apis/1179/saltstack-config-raas/) to automate tasks using Python.
I am unable to use .format with any of the methods and I do not understand why. Here is an example

This does not work:

```
from sseapiclient import APIClient
client = APIClient('http://myaac.com', username, password)

mycommand = 'cmd="local",fun="test.ping",tgt={"saltmaster":{"tgt":"minion*","tgt_type":"glob"}}'
client.api.cmd.route_cmd('{}'.format(mycommand))
```

I get an error message:

```
"3004: Request validation failure.
  job_uuid:
    - Not a valid UUID.
  cmd:
    - Expected 'cmd'"
```

which if I understand correctly means that the value passed via .format is not considered.

However, passing parameters directly works fine:

```
from sseapiclient import APIClient
client = APIClient('http://myaac.com', username, password)

client.api.cmd.route_cmd(cmd="local",fun="test.ping",tgt={"saltmaster":{"tgt":"minion*","tgt_type":"glob"}})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: create a dictionary and unpack it using `**`

Comment: well, I would expect that you will get `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'` with the code you show- `{}.format(mycommand)`. Even if you mean `'{}'.format()`, I don't see why the use of `format()` in this case

Comment: Passing multiple arguments like this (single string) will not work as you expect. See @AbdulNiyasPM comment above

Comment: @buran my apologies. I missed the single quotes sorry. The reason I use .format is because "mycommand" is a dynamic string that I have to construct ahead of the API call

Comment: It shouldn't be a string at all. Why not call and pass arguments dynamically (i.e. with the desired values)?

Comment: @Norskyi and why does it need to be a string specifically? If at all it is a user provided value consider taking a JSON object from them. Executing arbitrary code from strings is just going to make more problems for you.

Comment: Thanks @AbdulNiyasPM, I'll give that a try!

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat. I am going to try to unpack it from dict as was suggested. Late night coding here, perhaps I am overthinking things.

Comment: Thank you @AbdulNiyasPM. That worked
I wasn't thinking clearly. Not sure why I was convinced the string will do it for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General function to turn string into \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141237/general-function-to-turn-string-into-kwargs)

Answer (score 1):

[`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is used for formatting strings. `'{}'.format(a)` is just the same as `str(a)`.

`route_cmd` is expecting several arguments, in particular one named `cmd`. Passing it a single string will not work.

If you want to store named arguments in a single variable, you should use a `dict`:

```py
mycommand = {"cmd": "local", "fun": "test.ping", 
             "tgt": {"saltmaster": {"tgt":"minion*", "tgt_type":"glob"}}
client.api.cmd.route_cmd(**mycommand)
```